# My transaction has been on pending for 27hrs

Tags: blockchain.info

I need to know how to confirm my transaction it's been on pending for a while and I really need the transaction [image]

Comment: Your transaction size is 224 bytes and you are paying a fee of 678 satoshis, which means you are paying a transaction fee of 3 sat/byte, which is too small. You can check https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/, to see what the current fee prices are and the average time to be included in the block.,

Comment: @ugamkamat how can I do it because I need this money urgently